# rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant Warden. Rails 3.2.22 Ruby 2.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following this tutorial:

http://lucatironi.net/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/

Using ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 3.2.22.

I am getting the following error message:

```
    rake aborted!
    NameError: uninitialized constant Warden
```

My Gemfile is:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

     gem 'rails', '3.2.22'

             # Bundle edge Rails instead:
     # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

     gem 'devise-token_authenticatable'

     gem 'sqlite3'

     gem 'warden'
     #gem 'mysql'
     #gem 'mysql2'

     gem 'devise'

     gem 'therubyracer'
     gem 'execjs'

             # Gems used only for assets and not required
             # in production environments by default.
             group :assets do
       gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
       gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

       # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more    supported runtimes
       # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

       gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
     end

      gem 'jquery-rails'

      # To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
      # gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

      # To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
      # gem 'jbuilder'

      # Use unicorn as the app server
      # gem 'unicorn'

      # Deploy with Capistrano
      # gem 'capistrano'

      # To use debugger
      # gem 'debugger'
```

Trace log:

```
     pc@acer:~/rubycode/layer_app$ rake db:create db:migrate --trace
     ** Invoke db:create (first_time)
     ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
     ** Execute db:load_config
     ** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
     ** Execute rails_env
     ** Execute db:create
     db/development.sqlite3 already exists
     db/test.sqlite3 already exists
     ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
     ** Invoke environment (first_time)
     ** Execute environment
     rake aborted!
     NoMethodError: undefined method `token_authentication_key=' for         
    Devise:Module/home/pc/rubycode/layer_app/config/initializers/devise.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
     /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise.rb:278:in `setup'
     /home/pc/rubycode/layer_app/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `each'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    /home/pc/rubycode/layer_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
     /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
     /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
     /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
     /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
     /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-   3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
      /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
      /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
      /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
      /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
     /home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
     Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

I am not sure what the problem is, and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Warden is a dependency of Devise. That is where it is coming from.

Comment: Can you add/is Warden in your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Yes, I found Warden in the Gemfile.lock. Warden 1.2.3.

Comment: Is Devise in your Gemfile? I would try adding `require 'devise'` to your application.rb

Comment: please include the trace that ruby put out for the error (basically all of the long list of files and messages that go along with an error), this problem may lie outside of the gemfile.